# Find the max and min values of a tree in clojure

Tags: clojure, tree

I need to Develop a function called bounds which takes a nested list of numbers as its only argument (ie: a tree). Bounds should return the largest &smallest value in the tree.
Eg: = = (bounds '(1 (-2 17 (4) -8 (-6 13) (-8 17)
I have got a short version using apply max apply min and flatten I just can't get my head it

Using clojure

Comment: Post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `flatten` function:

```
(defn bounds
  [& args]
  (let [flat-vals (flatten args) ]  ;=> (1 -2 17 4 -8 -6 13)
    [ (apply min flat-vals) (apply max flat-vals) ] ))

(println 
  (bounds '(1 (-2 17 (4)) -8 (-6 13))))
;=> [-8 17]
```

P.S.  It is easier (no quoting required!) if you write your lists as vectors:

```
(println 
  (bounds [1 [-2 17 [4]] -8 [-6 13]] ))
;=> [-8 17]
```

Comment: Please click the up-vote and the "answered" boxes! Thanks, Alan

Comment: Flatten does the recursion for you:  https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6843

Comment: Also see postwalk and postwalk-demo:   http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/postwalk-demo   and   http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/postwalk